# Linq Expression Chain Syntax for In Query

Tags: vb.net, linq, inner-join, linq-expressions

I have a query that I cannot seem to replicate in expression method chain syntax. I have two tables "User" and "UserPayment". User and UserPayment have a one to many relation i.e. One User can have many UserPayments.

Just wondering what the syntax is to get all users that have made a payment on a certain date? Or even get all users that have made a payment at all?

Also to note I am writing in VB.

Thanks

Comment: If you download and put your query into LinqPad, there is a tab which shows the query expression using the chain syntax.  It displays in C#, I think, but it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be able to hit the UserPayments, use a `where` clause to filter by your date, and get the distinct Users from there.

Something like this?

```
 Dim users = From up In db.UserPayments _
    Where up.PaymentDate >= someDate _
    Select up.User Distinct
```

The VB dot-notation escapes me, but in C#, I'd do this (sorry I can't get you quite exactly what you're looking for):

```
var users = db.UserPayments.Where(x=>x.PayDate.Date == someDate)
                           .Select(x=>x.User)
                           .Distinct();
```

Comment: What is the expression method syntax for this?